# TSQL - Need to compare values of two most recent rows in logging table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `INDICATORS` that stores details and current scores of performance indicators. I have another table `IND_HISTORIES` that stores historical values of the indicator scores. Data are stored from `INDICATORS` to `IND_HISTORIES` at set periods (ie quarterly), to establish score / rating trends.

`IND_HISTORIES` has a column structure similar to this-

```
pk_IndHistId  fk_IndId  Score  DateSaved
```

Rating levels are also defined, meaning a score value of 1 to 3 is Low, 4 to 6 is Avg, and 7 to 9 is High.

I am trying to build an alert feature, whereby a record will be returned if it's most recent rating level (based on most recent score in `IND_HISTORIES`) is greater than it's second-most recent rating level (based on second-most recent score in `IND_HISTORIES`).

I am using code like below to build a temp table that translates score values to rating level thresholds...

```
-- opt_IND_ScoreValues = 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
DECLARE @tblScores TABLE (idx int identity, val int not null)
INSERT INTO @tblScores (val) SELECT IntValue FROM dbo.fn_getSettingList('opt_IND_ScoreValues')

-- opt_IND_RatingLevels = Low;Low;Low;Avg;Avg;Avg;High;High;High
DECLARE @tblRatings TABLE (idx int identity, txt nvarchar(128))
INSERT INTO @tblRatings (txt) SELECT TxtValue FROM dbo.fn_getSettingList('opt_IND_RatingLevels')

-- combine two tables above using a common index
DECLARE @tblRatingScores TABLE (val int, txt nvarchar(128))
INSERT INTO @tblRatingScores SELECT s.val, r.txt FROM @tblScores s JOIN @tblRatings r ON s.idx = r.idx

-- reduce table rows above to find score thresholds for each rating level
DECLARE @tblRatingBands TABLE (idx int identity, score int not null, rating nvarchar(128))
INSERT INTO @tblRatingBands
SELECT rs.val, rs.txt FROM @tblRatingScores rs
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(val) as val FROM @tblRatingScores GROUP BY txt) AS x ON rs.txt = x.txt AND rs.val = x.val
ORDER BY val
```

**QUESTION:** Is there an elegant query I can run against the `IND_HISTORIES` table that will return records where the most recent rating level for an `INDICATOR` is above the second-most recent rating level?

**UPDATE:** To clarify, `INDICATORS` is not used in the calculation - it's a parent table that holds general information of the performance measure and current 'volatile' scores. Scores are saved to `IND_HISTORY` periodically - this provides point-in-time 'snapshots' of data, helping to establish score trends.

I'm looking to query the `IND_HISTORY` table, to find where the most recent 'snapshot' value of an indicator is higher than its second-most recent 'snapshot' value. (It would be ideal to also join the Rating Levels table, as described above, in the determination, so that rows are only returned if the score increase results in a Rating Level increase.)

Any solution should be compatible with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Can you clarify: 1. Is the `INDICATORS` table used at all in your calculations - it's not clear from your description. Can you add the SQL Server version to the tags, as a lot of Analytical functions were added in SQL 2012. Also is there any reason you are using table valued functions to get data out of the table? Why not select and join directly from the source table without all the intermediate functions and table variables?

Comment: Update added above. I'm not sure about your question re: table valued functions / intermediate functions. Hopefully my explanation helps.

Comment: `dbo.fn_getSettingList('opt_IND_ScoreValues')`,  is a table valued function - does this have any relationship to `IND_HISTORY` ? why not just select out of those tables directly without table valued functions and table variables like `@tblScores`

Comment: The table valued functions are used to obtain configuration settings. Sorry for any confusion, but those pieces of code are not related to the `IND_HISTORY` table; they are intended to show how `IND_HISTORIES.Score` values are translated to textual rating levels (ie Low, Avg, High).

Comment: After researching a bit on the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, I was able to construct my own solution, which I've added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented the below, which seems to work. But I'd be interested to hear any recommendations to optimize or consolidate.

First, I realize that I do not need the last temp table `@tblRatingBands` constructed above. Instead, I simply select matching text ratings from `@tblRatingScores` in my first query set below.

Then in the final query, I check if the score value has increased and if the rating text has changed -- this indicates the trend score has increased and resulted in a change to the rating level.

```
DECLARE @tblTrendScores TABLE (indId int not null, ih_date datetime, rowNo int, ih_score int, rating nvarchar(128));

WITH LastTwoScores AS (
  SELECT fk_IndId,
         DateSaved,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_IndId ORDER BY DateSaved DESC) AS RowNo,
         Score
  FROM Ind_History
)
INSERT INTO @tblTrendScores
SELECT *,
       (SELECT txt FROM @tblRatingScores WHERE val = Score)
FROM LastTwoScores
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 AND 2
ORDER BY fk_IndId, RowNo

SELECT a.indId,
       a.ih_date,
       CASE  WHEN ((a.ih_score > IsNull(b.ih_score, 0)) AND (a.rating <> IsNull(b.rating, 'none'))) THEN 'Up'
             WHEN ((a.ih_score < IsNull(b.ih_score, 0)) AND (a.rating <> IsNull(b.rating, 'none'))) THEN 'Down'
             ELSE 'no-change'
       END AS TrendRatingChange
FROM @tblTrendScores a
  JOIN @tblTrendScores b ON a.indId = b.indId AND b.rowNo = 2
WHERE a.rowNo = 1
```

Comment: I suspect that you don't need any of the table variables. You can effectively do joins into functions (if that's the issue) using CROSS APPLY also. But I'm glad you sorted your issue.